# SP13 - How can i see/edit the settings(Target Label Behavior)

Tags: sharepoint-server, splistitem, list-item, splist, variations

**My issue is:**

Where i approve changed data on listitem in source List, data in target listItem has been changed.

[**-References-**](http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/variations-in-sharepoint-2013-tutorial-21775.aspx)

**I can to see the setting on source in existing variation site:**
[image]

Comment: Any help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this technet article, perhaps help
[SharePoint 2013 Variations – Initial setup and configuration for variations site](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepoint_quick_reads/2013/08/11/sharepoint-2013-variations-initial-setup-and-configuration-for-variations-site/#comment-3925)